# SharePoint Designer 2007: Filtering on columns not working when using query string parameters

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a DVWP.  I can't make the filtering on column work properly (`the option for sort and filtering on column is selected`).

Under the Common Data View Tasks I have 2 Filter criteria.  One criteria has a static value...the other one is a query string parameter.

The form displays the data filtered correctly but when I try using the filtering on column is not displaying anything (just the sort options but not the filter).

I've read other posts and decided to try removing the filter criteria and enabling the `Add XSLT Filtering` option and adding the criteria there.  Again, the forms display the data correctly filtered but when I go to the column filter, now it shows ALL of the records instead of only the ones on the form (based on the filter criteria results only).

Please help!

Thank you!